# Connect to Powershell Just Enough Administration (JEA) endpoint over WinRm with Certificate authorization

Tags: powershell, security, powershell-remoting, winrm, windows-server-2019

Is it possible Connect to Powershell Just Enough Administration (JEA) endpoint over WinRm with Certificate authorization?

When **RunAsVirtualAccount = $true** ??

Source: Windows Server 2019 Std Target: Windows Server 2019 Std , same subnet, WorkGroup, FW off.

1. When **RunAsVirtualAccount = $false** and endpoint configured with **RunAsAccount** (Local admin) , and authentication **Certificate or Login/Password**.... Connection OK
2. When **RunAsVirtualAccount = $True** and authentication type - **Login / Password.**... Connection OK
3. When **RunAsVirtualAccount = $true** and  authentication type - **Certificate Thumbprint**... Connection **FAIL!!!** Whith error:

> `PS C:\Windows\system32> enter-PSSession -CertificateThumbprint
>   f0ee9dc3344f05673fc6e134bteeb2764ee00d7 -ComputerName
>   hqtstweb3.contoso.com  -SessionOption $SessionOptions -UseSSL
>   -ConfigurationName GetUpdatesDMZ
>
>       enter-PSSession : Connecting to remote server hqtstweb3.contoso.com failed with the following error message : An internal error occurred.
>   For more information, see the about_Remote_Troubleshooting Help topic.
>       At line:1 char:1
>       + enter-PSSession -CertificateThumbprint f0ee9dc3344f05673fc6e134b24eeb ...
>       + ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
>           + CategoryInfo          : InvalidArgument: (hqtstweb3.contoso.com:String) [Enter-PSSession],
>   PSRemotingTransportException
>           + FullyQualifiedErrorId : CreateRemoteRunspaceFailed`

And Event on target server:

```
The WSMan service could not launch a host process to process the given request. Make sure the WSMan provider host server and proxy are properly registered. Error code 1359
```

.

```
$SessionOptions = New-PSSessionOption -SkipCACheck -SkipCNCheck -OperationTimeout 360000
```

PsSession configuration files:
https://drive.google.com/file/d/1imnUg706_J-cjpE68pYu0AXqzhRydu_p/view